# Making navbar elements equal width and equal distance from each other

Tags: css

I'm still struggling a lot with html and css. If you take a look at this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvunmo2n/

HTML:

```
<div class="headerBar">

</div> <!-- end headerBar -->

<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="h">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="o">Past Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="c">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="a">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}

body{
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #a0c4ff;

}

.headerBar{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

.headerBar #logo{
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 12.5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu {
margin-top: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
text-align: justify;
min-width: 500px;
height: 30px;
font-family: Opensans;
}

.menu:after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}

.menu li {
display: inline-block;
}

.menu a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The distance between the left side of the screen and the left side of the "Home" element and the distance between the right side of the screen and the right side of the "Contact Us" element are different. I want them to be equal so that the navbar doesn't look bad. I'm really not sure how to edit the css to make this happen.

Comment: You just need to add `padding: 0;` to `.menu`. A `ul` has default padding that the browser applies. You might also look into reset stylesheets or something like [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I also want to make it so that when I hover over it the whole distance between the element being hovered over and the elements either side turn a different colour. At the moment if I use .menu a:hover only the area directly around the text changes colour. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```css
#wrapper{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}

body{
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #a0c4ff;

}

.headerBar{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

.headerBar #logo{
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 12.5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
text-align: justify;
min-width: 500px;
height: 30px;
font-family: Opensans;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerBar">

</div> <!-- end headerBar -->

<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="h">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="o">Past Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="c">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" accesskey="a">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```